# Large “error_log” file

Tags: error, log

Site is working fine but `Apache` generate big error log every time I hit the website.

As I have investigate : it is cause of illegal char in XML

```
[26-Sep-2016 11:40:47] invalid cache data for cacheId[config_global] {<config><global><install><date>Mon, 22 Jun 2015 13:51:26 +0000</date></install><resources><default_setup><connection><persistent>0</persistent><host>localhost</host><username></username><password></password><dbname></dbname><initStatements>
```

Then after a long xml file of 3MB t